# Alert icon not closing in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: jquery, button, icons

The below is code which I used:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertDanger" style="display:none">
    <p style="width:100%"><i class="sg-icon sg-icon-warning fa fa-info-circle"></i><span class="alert-message"></span><button class="closeClass"><i class="sg-icon sg-icon-x fa fa-times"></i></button></p>
</div>

 $('.closeClass').click(function () {
            $('#alertDanger').hide();
            $('#alertWarning').hide();
            $('#alertSuccess').hide();
        })
```

Comment: any idea why it is not working in firefox?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve and what is not working in the body of the question and create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: maybe place a screenshot of the problem.